# Linux bash: destination directory given by user, stored in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am required to create a script in linux bash, where at some point the user can enter a path to a directory. For this I should use `read -p` command. Then I should check if directory exists. My code below works fine until the user tries to enter `~/path`. The code does not recognize symbol ~ as Home directory. Any suggestions?

```
read -p "Please, enter the destination: "
    if [ -d "$REPLY" ]; then
        echo "Directory exists!"
    fi
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to replace `~` with `"$HOME"` yourself. There are also other types of tilde expansion, which you generally use less often, such as `~user` to get user's homedir instead of your own. Assuming you only care about the first case, then a parameter expansion will do

```
read -ep 'Please, enter the destination: ' dir
dir=${dir/#~/$HOME}
if [[ -d $dir ]]; then
    printf 'Good job, the directory exists!\n'
fi
```

You might notice I added -e to the read command. This makes read use the readline library to read in the directory. That means the user may use tab-completion.

See [BashFAQ 100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) for more on string manipulations in bash.

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

In general you should avoid (and encourage people to avoid) using `~` expansion except directly at the shell prompt.

That said if you *do* have to deal with it and want to support all of the various extended bash tilde expansions you can use something like my [tildeExpand.sh](https://github.com/deryni/tildeExpand.sh) script.